# Windows 11 stops working after screen turns back on

Tags: windows-11, intel-graphics

In the power settings I have Windows turn off the screen after 10 minutes (never going to sleep). When turning the screen back on using the mouse for example, Windows starts a weird behavior: I cannot close app windows anymore, I can't save or open files although parts of the open apps' UI still work, the start menu is partially broken and I can't turn off or restart the PC.
Here is the detailed setup:

- Core i7-12700k (using iGPU)
- Windows 11 Professionnal up-to-date with up-to-date Intel graphics driver
- Dell UP3216Q UHD monitor running at 3840x2160 @ 60Hz over HDMI 2.0
- AsRock Z690M-ITX motherboard with up-to-date BIOS and chipset driver

This seems to happen less with smaller resolutions (I will be able to test that again in a few days, I can't test it right now).
Also, I tried turning off Windows fast startup since I saw that it could fix this problem but it did not change anything.

Comment: Update BIOS and Power Drivers.  Then set Power Management settings to default.  Restart and check screen behavior

Comment: What do you mean by power drivers ? I added the BIOS and chipset driver updates, the problem remains the same. If anything, it seems to be a Windows bug since everything seems to work fine at the hardware level (the screen turns back on etc., only system calls crash)

Comment: Look in your Manufacturer's site. Power drivers manage power and battery and even if no battery, power drivers help with sleep and screen.

Comment: It's a custom build, so no manufacturer per se. As for AsRock, I downloaded every possible driver from their website.